# How can I set the deleted flag manually in TYPO3?

Tags: repository, typo3, extbase

I am using a command controller and the scheduler module to import a car list into TYPO3. This list contains only available cars, so if a car is removed from the list I want to set the deleted flag into database to 1 for this car, but I am missing a setter like this:

```
$car->setDeleted(1);
```

So how can I set this property manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get an extbase repository for cars, and then call its `remove()` method with the car you want to mark as deleted.

Something along these lines:

```
class YourCommandController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController {

    /**
     * @var \Yourvendor\Yourextkey\Domain\Repository\CarRepository
     * @inject
     */
    protected $carRepository;

    /**
     * Deletes some car.
     */
    public function deleteCarCommand() {
        $car = ... // get hold of the car to delete somehow, probably using the repository

        $this->carRepository->remove($car); // This should suffice!
    }

}
```